# How do I resolve this bug when setting up log in authentication system in react?

Tags: reactjs, api, post, axios, authorization

Please I need a set of expert eyes on these real quick :

what would happen if the error did not come up

[image]

header:
[image]

body:
[image]

The login page would collect the user's gmail and password , send it to the login url and get an object containing the authorization token would be returned. Works perfectly on postman.

Inside vscode :

This is the function handle the authorization:

```
  const [loginInput, setLoginInput] = React.useState({
      email: '',
      password: ''
  })


const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
      const response = await axios.post('https://adscamp.thevootblog.com/api/v1/users/login',
        JSON.stringify(loginInput.username, loginInput.password),
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${response?.token}`
         }
        }
      );
      console.log(response)

    }catch(err){
         console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

I'm not getting the object

[image]
"cannot access 'response' before initialization" ,which means response is empty.

extra information :
I imported axios into login.js file from another file :

api(folder) => api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
})
```

Comment: You needs to share header and body screen of Postman. And do you have the Get Token documentation of URL?

Comment: @BenchVue No i do not have it. I have included the header and body screen in my question.

Comment: I added my answer, now you need to hide your password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is node.js code

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            url = 'https://adscamp.thevootblog.com/api/v1/users/login',
            data = {
              'email': 'oluwatomiwaibikunle@gmail.com',
              'password': '<your password>'
            },
            config = {
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
            }
        )
        return Promise.resolve(response.data.token)
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
}

getToken()
    .then((token) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(token, null, 4))
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Install dependency

```
npm install axios
```

Result

[image]

Curl commend

```
curl --location 'https://adscamp.thevootblog.com/api/v1/users/login' \
--silent \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "email": "oluwatomiwaibikunle@gmail.com",
  "password": "your password"
}' | jq
```

Result
[image]

Now you needs to hide your password.

Comment: I can't write in node.js, The code in my question was written in pure js.

Comment: You can use `const response = await axios.post(...)`  in your react.js without change.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can only `JSON.stringify` JSON objects

change

```
 JSON.stringify(loginInput.username, loginInput.password)
```

to

```
 JSON.stringify({loginInput.username, loginInput.password})
```

And the error you are seeing is because you're trying to access the response inside the headers before even the http request initalized.

the purpose of this HTTP request is to get the `Authorization Token` so remove the Authorization header.

and remove the line

```
'Authorization': `Bearer ${response?.token}`
```